# vb.net check if word exists in string and act accordingly

Tags: string, vb.net

I read a text file, remove all punctuations and than read all the words in a `String()`. I want to count the words so I need some `String()` with two fields, word and frequency. Before I add a word I count the amount of times it is occuring in the text with the `Function CountMyWords`. If the word already is in the `String()` I dont want to add it again, just increase it's frequency.

```
Private Sub CreateWordList()

        Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\shakespear.txt")

        text = Regex.Replace(text, "[^A-Za-z']+", " ")
        Dim words As String() = text.Split(New Char() {" "c})
        Dim i As Integer

        For Each word As String In words
            If Len(word) > 5 Then
                word = word.ToLower()
                'now check if the word already exists
                If words.Contains(word) = True Then

                End If
                i = CountMyWords(text, word)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", word + " " + i.ToString)
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
    Private Function CountMyWords(input As String, phrase As String) As Integer

        Dim Occurrences As Integer = 0
        Dim intCursor As Integer = 0
        Do Until intCursor >= input.Length

            Dim strCheckThisString As String = Mid(LCase(input), intCursor + 1, (Len(input) - intCursor))
            Dim intPlaceOfPhrase As Integer = InStr(strCheckThisString, phrase)
            If intPlaceOfPhrase > 0 Then
                Occurrences += 1
                intCursor += (intPlaceOfPhrase + Len(phrase) - 1)
            Else
                intCursor = input.Length
            End If
        Loop
        CountMyWords = Occurrences

    End Function
```

Any thought how to do that?

Comment: This comment is a supplement to all the answers suggesting a dictionary. A dictionary has a constant access time, i.e., it does not depend on the number of items it contains to find an entry. This makes it very quick. See also [Collections and Data Structures / Algorithmic complexity of collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/#algorithmic-complexity-of-collections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66858551/1115360), I suggest using a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2), but you might not need the overhead of having a class as the value in the dictionary.

Also, if you're using fairly large files, you can process them one line at a time with the [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines) method instead of reading the whole lot into RAM.

You can make the processing of the text a little terser with some LINQ, like this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brunoklein99/deep-learning-notes/master/shakespeare.txt
        Dim src = "C:\temp\TheSonnets.txt"
        Dim wordsWithCounts As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

        For Each line In File.ReadLines(src)
            Dim text = Regex.Replace(line, "[^A-Za-z']+", " ")
            Dim words = text.Split({" "c}).
                Where(Function(s) s.Length > 5).
                Select(Function(t) t.ToLower())

            For Each w In words
                If wordsWithCounts.ContainsKey(w) Then
                    wordsWithCounts(w) += 1
                Else
                    wordsWithCounts.Add(w, 1)
                End If
            Next

        Next

        ' extracting some data as an example...
        Dim mostUsedFirst = wordsWithCounts.
            Where(Function(x) x.Value > 18).
            OrderByDescending(Function(y) y.Value)

        For Each w As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In mostUsedFirst
            Console.WriteLine(w.Key & " " & w.Value)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

With the example text, this outputs:

```
beauty 52
should 44
though 33
praise 28
love's 26
nothing 19
better 19
```

Comment: If I run the code the program freezes when I try to write the console,writeline

Comment: @Marco Does it give any sort of error message? If you used your own file instead of the one I tested it with, can you give a link to somewhere to download it from so I can check it with that?

Comment: @steve no message at all. Just stops running

Comment: @Marco It can be a bit funny with a KeyValuePair in a For Each loop - does it work with the change I made to add `As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)`?

Comment: still freezes. Maybe this code? Dim mostUsedFirst = wordsWithCounts.....

Comment: @Marco If you comment out all the parts with `mostUsedFirst` and just put in `Console.WriteLine(wordsWithCounts.Count)`, does that work?

Comment: That works, it returns 31. But at the line: Console.ReadLine() it still freezes

Comment: @Marco I put Console.ReadLine() in so that the output doesn't disappear off the screen (with my settings). Just press the Enter key.

Comment: @Marco Aha! If you change the `18` in `Where(Function(x) x.Value > 18)` to `1`, do you see output? With my test data there were lots of words: it looks like you are using a smaller dataset, so there would not be any words repeated more than 18 times.

Comment: Indeed I had a very small text file. Changed the value to > 1. Now I get results. Although the code still crashes on Console.ReadLine

Comment: @Marco Just take out the `Console.ReadLine()` if you don't need it ;)

Comment: Could I use this code to read all files in a folder and make one big wordlist with frequencies?

Comment: @Marco Yes, you could. *After* the line `Dim wordsWithCounts As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`, you could add a loop like `For Each src In Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Your\Directory\Name")` (and put the `Next` after the other two `Next` lines, of course).

Comment: It does work and returns an extended list, although the files are pdf and not txt. Maybe I have to change something there

Comment: @Marco Yes, a search for ".net extract plain text from pdf" should give you a few possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a different approach. The first thing to do is to create a class that represent the word frequency. It is just a string for the word and an integer to count the word repetitions

```
Public Class WordFrequency
    Public Property Word As String
    Public Property Frequency As Integer
End Class
```

Now, you can create a dictionary where the key is the word and the value is an instance of the WordFrequency class. Using a dictionary is a great bonus in searching if an item exists in the collection. You use a syntax similar to the one used for arrays and specific methods exist to find the element in the collection. So your code becomes simply

```
' Declared at the global class level
Dim wordCounter As Dictionary(Of String, WordFrequency) = New Dictionary(Of String, WordFrequency)
.....

Private Sub CreateWordList()

    Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\shakespear.txt")
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "[^A-Za-z']+", " ")

    ' remove any blank entries eventually created by the replace
    Dim words As String() = text.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For Each word As String In words
        If word.Length > 5 Then
            word = word.ToLower()
            ' If we don't have the word in the dictionary, create the entry
            If Not wordCounter.ContainsKey(word) Then
                wordCounter.Add(word, New WordFrequency With 
                {
                    .Word =  word, 
                    .Frequency = 0
                })
            End If

            ' just increment the property frequency from the dictionary Value 
            wordCounter(Word).Frequency += 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that instead of having a Value of type WordFrequency you can just use an integer for the frequency, but I prefer to have a class because if you ever need to expand the informations kept in the dictionary a class will be easily extended

Comment: Seems like `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` is already good enough on it's own. No need for the custom class.

Comment: Yes, it is enough as explained in the last phrase. Just using a class because these things usually tend to explode in new requirements to handle

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a Dictionary:

```vb
Public Function CountWords(words As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    For Each word As String In words
        If result.ContainsKey(word)
            result(word)+=1
        Else
            result.Add(word, 1)
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub CreateWordList(filePath As String)
    Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(filePath).ToLower()
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-z']+", " ")

    Dim words As IEnumerable(Of String) = text.Split(New Char() {" "c}).
                                               Where(Function(w) w.Length > 5)
    Dim wordCounts As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = CountMyWords(words)

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In wordCounts
       Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} {kvp.Value}")
    Next
End Sub
```